# Is it possible to refer to regular class names using module.css/module.scss?

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-modules, classname

This might be a dumb question, but I am relatively new to using the `CSS`/`SCSS` modules with `React`.

And I have valid reasons for asking, as modules allow scoping of `CSS` (which is useful to prevent `CSS` conflicts), but often when using external libraries (like `Material-UI` or `devextreme`) for built-in components, it is needed to override given `CSS`.

For example (I'll use `devextreme` for better illustration):

```js
// ...other imports
import Textbox from 'devextreme-react/text-box';

const nameLabel = {'aria-label': 'Demo'}

function App () {
    // imagine a straightforward example,
    return (
        <Textbox placeholder="Demo" inputAttr={nameLabel} />
    )
}
```

Usually, it is possible to do like below if, for example, I want no padding:

```
.dx-texteditor.dx-editor-filled .dx-texteditor-input {
    padding: 0;
}
```

There are surely other ways (like setting `id` or inline-styling), but it would be great to know if it is possible. Thank you for your kind attention, and all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**let see how we can override built-in components css**

- consider you have below a regular css in global-styles.scss file

```
.yourRegularClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

- you can use the :global selector to refer to above global class
- define your local App.module.css, here the `composes` keyword is used to compose styles from another component's module

```
:global {
  .yourRegularClass {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}


.myModuleClass {
  color: red;
  
  .dxTexteditornput {
    composes: dxTexteditornput from '~path-to/DevextremeComponent/module.scss';
   padding: 0;
  }
}
```

- update component by importing above local `App.module.css`. here css class dx-texteditor-input from devextreme-react been overridden

```
import Textbox from 'devextreme-react/text-box';

import styles from './App.module.css';



function App () {
    // imagine a straightforward example,
    return (

      <div className={styles.myModuleClass}>This is a module class</div>

      <div className={`yourRegularClass ${styles.myModuleClass}`}>
        This uses both a global and a module class
      </div>

        <Textbox placeholder="Demo" className={styles.dxTexteditornput} />
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi Sahab, thank you for your answer, I think I understand it, but what about the specificity if the library ones has like `(0, 2, 0)` or even more, while self-defined classes are not enough to override it?

Comment: thanks for comment , kindly explain a little more "library ones has like (0, 2, 0) or even more"

Comment: I'd use `dxtextbox` as an example, though you might need to navigate to its websites: [React Textbox - Overview - DevExtreme](https://js.devexpress.com/React/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TextBox/Overview/MaterialBlueLight/). If you open the `Elements` devtools, you can find that many styling of it have more than 2 class specifiers on the component. For example, `.dx-texteditor.dx-editor-filled .dx-placeholder::before, .dx-texteditor.dx-editor-filled .dx-texteditor-input, .dx-texteditor.dx-editor-outlined .dx-placeholder::before, .dx-texteditor.dx-editor-outlined .dx-texteditor-input` for padding.

Comment: seems like i need to have more knowledge regarding devexpress before update my answer

Comment: I think it's fine as this question does not apply to `devextreme` library only, but also to other libraries that might have probably 3-4 class selectors on a single group of `CSS`. And I'd like to know what's the method to get past it, and if Module `CSS` has provided anything for referring to regular `CSS`. Great thanks anyway!

Comment: i have updated my answer kindly have a look

Comment: I see, very interesting with the `:global` keyword. Great thanks Sahab!